# How to get a pdf from nodejs and show in new browser tab with vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js

I have a button in a vuejs template.

This button when clicked request a pdf from my node backend.

Next, I have  a code to show the pdf dowloaded into a new chrome browser tab.

My problem is that I always get tbhis error: "error failed to load pdf document".
What´s is wrong here?

//nodejs

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const axios = require("axios");

router.post("/getPDF", async (req, res) => {
  const url = req.body.url;
  const dados = await axios(url, {
    headers: {
      authorization: "Guest",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    method: "GET",
    responseType: "blob", //Force to receive data in a Blob Format
  });
  res.contentType("application/pdf");
  res.send({ data: dados.data });
});
```

//vuejs

```
<template>
...
<v-btn
   @click.stop="fVisualizarBula(item[header.value])"></v-btn>
...
</template>

export default {
...
methods:{
async fVisualizarBula(pIdAnexo) {
      const filePDFURL = `https://samplesite/api/consulta/medicamentos/arquivo/bula/parecer/${pIdAnexo}/?Authorization=`;
      try {
        const response = await ServicePDF.getPDF({ url: filePDFURL });
        //Create a Blob from the PDF Stream
        const file = new Blob([response.data], {
          type: "application/pdf",
        });
        console.log(file)
        //Build a URL from the file
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        //Open the URL on new Window
        window.open(
          fileURL,
          "_blank",
          "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=10,left=10,width=900,height=600"
        );
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
}
```

//sample of console.log(file)

```
Blob {size: 1110659, type: "application/pdf"}
size: 1110659
type: "application/pdf"
__proto__: Blob
arrayBuffer: ƒ arrayBuffer()
size: 1110659
slice: ƒ slice()
stream: ƒ stream()
text: ƒ text()
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 0
name: "text"
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[0]
type: (...)
constructor: ƒ Blob()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Blob"
get size: ƒ size()
get type: ƒ type()
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: My guess the URL is supposed to be dynamic and not `const`? Why create a button for a pdf download when there is one native to most browsers when displaying the pdf? If you wanted to do that a simple `<obj></obj>` tag should do the trick... I think.

Comment: @ShanerM13  Thank´s for your response. My post was adapted to show the problem. Actually, i have  v-datatable with many rows. Each row has a column  with a pdf button link. I didn´t understood what you mean about "const" to be a problem. I think the problem is not that. If I use a href link and the same url in a anchor, the pdf is asking to download and save. But I don´t want my users make the download and save, and next, to open and show the pdf file. I am doing the download on backend node server and sending to browser to show the pdf automatically. No need to user download an save the pdf

Comment: Ah, yes. Well so I skimmed, I thought for some reason you were trying to reassign a value assigned to a `const`, which is immutable. Which led me to think, "oh, you only to want show 1 pdf on the page for the users to download". I am going afk for a minute... brb

Comment: Does it work in Firefox?  Since downloading works, the code to generate the object/url seems ok.  In that case it could be more likely a problem with a malformed PDF.

Comment: @Dan  Sorry Dan. I didn´t tested in Firefox. I have no firefox installed for now. I am using chrome. As I said, if I use an anchor the download and save are ok. If there is malformed pdf, is there some error in my node code?

Comment: @Dan As I said, if I use an anchor the download and save are ok.In this case, my node backend is not used.

Comment: Yeah, very possibly an error with your express app if not a malformed PDF.  Is the PDF on the node server?  If so you shouldn't use axios in the express app to load it

Comment: @Dan  The pdf is not in my server. I am using axios. You can see my backend code in the post. I just put in the post a console.log of the file received in my  frontend.

Comment: response.data doesn't need more parsing, does it? In your vue.js

Comment: @ShanerM13 I changed my backend to:  router.post("/getPDF", async (req, res) => {
  const url = req.body.url;
  const dados = await axios(url, {
    headers: {
      authorization: "Guest",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    method: "GET",
    responseType: "arraybuffer", //Force to receive data in a Blob Format
  });
  res.send({ data: dados.data.toJSON() });
});    Now, it´s working.

Comment: In my frontend, I had to use: const file = new Blob([new Buffer(response.data.data)], {
          type: "application/pdf",
        });